# TransformError with babel-preset-react-native/index.js

Tags: react-native

I'm brand new to react-native, and trying to render my first bit of text on the screen.

When I run `react-native run-ios` and then click into my sample app, I see the following error:

[TransformError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.../albums/node_modules/babel-preset-react-native/index.js' while processing preset '.../babel-preset-react-native/index.js' RCTFatal RCTCxxBridge handleError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x3M3.png)

index.js DOES exist in my project, with the following code:

`'use strict';`
`module.exports = require('./configs/main');`

So far, I have tried the following:

1) Re-installing npm for babel-preset-react-native

2) Using yarn to remove and then re-add babel-preset-react-native
`yarn remove babel-preset-react-native`
`yarn add babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0`

3) Deleting babel.rc entirely

Nothing has worked. Eager to hear advice and suggestions for other things to try.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is bug in the new version of `babel-preset-react-native` as it will added automatically after you run `react-native init` command

Please take a look at this github issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15513

Workaround, try to change the version:

```
yarn remove babel-preset-react-native
yarn add babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0
```

if that's not work for you, try to remove trailing comma at `node_modules/babel-preset-react-native/configs/main.js` at this code below

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6ad7e8281b37ee2ce6425363c0b17420d056807a/babel-preset/configs/main.js#L40
and re-run your app

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I had tried these remove and add commands before, but I hadn't closed the React Packager terminal after running them. After closing the terminal and running the commands, I was back in business.

Comment: It works for me to. Same as @gfahs , i need to restart React Packager terminal.

Answer (score 4):

I got same problem yesterday and my way is:
 1. Go to `node_modules` and remove `babel-preset-react-native` folder.
 2. In root project type: `npm install babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0 --save-dev`

Hope you get this solved.

Comment: Thanks for responding! The other suggestions worked - but I'm totally keeping this in my back pocket, in case I encounter the issue again.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem yesterday and my way is:

1. Go to `node_modules` and remove `babel-preset-react-native` folder.
2. In root project type:
   `npm install babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0 --save-dev`

Hope you get this solved.

Thanks GaBACK

Comment: Please use comments, as this is not a new answer.