# Loading dependency graph, done. error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module ./../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, create-react-native-app

Getting the following error on running react native app in android emulator

react-native run-android

**Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js` from `D:\LW_Mobile\Projects\helloworld\App.js`: The module `./../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js` could not be found from `D:\LW_Mobile\Projects\helloworld\App.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
  * `D:\LW_Mobile\react-transform-hmr\lib\index.js(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`**

My Package.Json is

```js
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-functional-hmr": "^1.0.24",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.48.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

The babelrc is as following

```js
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "react", "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
  }
```

**Note:** working with expo is launching fine, This is the first time i am using the **react-native run-android** command

The System is looking into some different path and not within Node_Module. Is something related to this.?

Comment: Can you please upload your package.json

Comment: Updated my package.json

Comment: "babel-preset-react-native" Downgrade this version to this ---> 4.0.0 manually And then delete node modules and do npm install then let me know does it works or not.

Comment: no again the same error after setting 
 "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0" and i manually deleted the node_modlues folder and ran npm install

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760731/transformerror-with-babel-preset-react-native-index-js?answertab=votes#tab-top

Refer this answer

Comment: Thank you, I have tried as mentioned in the link, 
I dosen't help, getting the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181400/discussion-between-gowthaman-and-android-team).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution after lot of struggles.

1. Update all the packages such as Node and react native cli
2. In Android studio install **intel X86 Atom System Image**, **intel X86 Atom_64 System Image**
3. Close all the npm Terminal
4. Open a new Command prompt and run **react-native start --reset-cache**
5. Open a new Command prompt and run **react-native run-android**

Answer (score 1):

you can fix it by using these steps:

1. Close open all terminal or cmd.
2. replace dependency in package.json

   "react": "16.5.0" ,
   "react-native": "0.57.1"
3. execute this command.

   1. npm install @babel/runtime
   2. react-native start --reset-cache
   3. npm install
   4. react-native run-android